Complex multi level EF Core 8 inheritance issue
Please consider the following:

DB Context:
// DbContext.cs
public partial class OperationsDbContext : DbContext
{
  public virtual DbSet<AnimalBase> AnimalBases { get; set; }
  public virtual DbSet<Carnivore> Carnivores { get; set; }
  public virtual DbSet<Herbivore> Herbivores { get; set; }
  
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<AnimalBase>(entity =>
    {
      entity.UseTpcMappingStrategy();
    });
  }
}}

Entities:
// AnimalBase.cs
public abstract class AnimalBase
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Carnivore.cs
public class Carnivore : AnimalBase
{
}

// Herbivore.cs
public class Herbivore : AnimalBase
{
}

Controller:
// AnimalsController.cs
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AnimalsController : ControllerBase
{
  public async Task<Envelope<ReadAnimalDto>> Get()
  {
    var queryable = _context.Animals.ToListAsync();
    ...
  }
}

This works just fine. I end up with two db tables; Carnivores and Herbivores. I can extract both in one consecutive list. The ID will of course not be unique, which is expected.
Problem: Now I need to add region to the animals. Some application logic needs to be applied to the region, which is the same for both animal types.
Because carnivores and herbivores will have conflicting ID's, I've created separate (but similar) region entities for each animal type.
I modified the logic as follows:
DB Context:
// DbContext.cs
public partial class OperationsDbContext : DbContext
{
  public virtual DbSet<AnimalBase<RegionBase>> AnimalBases { get; set; }
  public virtual DbSet<Carnivore> Carnivores { get; set; }
  public virtual DbSet<Herbivore> Herbivores { get; set; }

  public virtual DbSet<RegionBase> RegionBases { get; set; }
  public virtual DbSet<CarnivoreRegion> CarnivoreRegions { get; set; }
  public virtual DbSet<HerbivoreRegion> HerbivoreRegions { get; set; }
  
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<AnimalBase<RegionBase>(entity =>
    {
      entity.UseTpcMappingStrategy();
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<RegionBase>(entity =>
    {
      entity.UseTpcMappingStrategy();
    });
  }
}}

Entities:
// AnimalBase.cs
public abstract class AnimalBase<T> 
  where T: RegionBase
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<RegionBase>? regions { get; set; }

  public double GetTotalRegionSize()
  {
    // Do some application logic
  }
}

// Carnivore.cs
public class Carnivore : AnimalBase<CarnivoreRegion>
{
  public override ICollection<CarnivoreRegion>? Regions { get; set; }
}

// Herbivore.cs
public class Herbivore : AnimalBase<HerbivoreRegion>
{
  public override ICollection<HerbivoreRegion>? Regions { get; set; }
}

// RegionBase.cs
public abstract class RegionBase
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public double Size { get; set; }
}

// CarnivoreRegion.cs
public class CarnivoreRegion : RegionBase
{
}

// HerbivoreRegion.cs
public class HerbivoreRegion : RegionBase
{
}

Controller:
// AnimalsController.cs
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AnimalsController : ControllerBase
{
  public async Task<Envelope<ReadAnimalDto>> Get()
  {
    var queryable = _context.Animals
      .Include(x => x.Regions)
      .ToListAsync();
    ...
  }
}

I get an The corresponding CLR type for entity type 'AnimalBase<RegionBase>' cannot be instantiated, and there is no derived entity type in the model that corresponds to a concrete CLR type. error.
The expected result of the above code is that I would have a single list of animals, each with a reference to their regions. (CarnivoreRegion for Carnivore entities, HerbivoreRegion for Herbivore entities).
I've concluded that this approach probably isn't possible, but any idea's on how to solve this beautifully?
Thanks!

If region is part of the type then each entity has to repeat region data. Region seems to make more sense as a container, i.e. 1:n related to animals, i.e. composition instead of inheritance. Inheritance is an "is a" relationship, composition is a "has a" relationship.

virtual ICollection<T>? not <RegionBase>. You may need to introduce a non generic AnimalBase base type for the DbSet.
